# HTTPS GET works on Browser but not via NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, axios, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to access the URL `<https://www.valueresearchonline.com/api/funds/trailing-returns-chart-new-vro/420>`. When I hit this on Google Chrome it works perfectly and I'm able to see the JSON response.

I've tried to run this via `Postman` as well and it works sometimes, but doesn't work on other instances (without changing anything).

I've the below code running on NodeJs. While executing, it throws an error `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403`.

I want to understand if at all there is a way to do this programatically. Or has the provider made arrangements at their end to stop such access.

Code:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
let data = '';

let config = {
  method: 'get',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'http://www.valueresearchonline.com/api/funds/trailing-returns-chart-new-vro/420',
  headers: { 
    'Cookie': '__cf_bm=J3u3clWuAwwUtmjRRm8Ojm41_S9yajNcV7tiRIdIyz8-1698608766-0-AbTn9Nl7Rbw8l52fTeYfvBJyCgt//3MZgKr+8pTKMGQCDU6EYvnblBi/Ubc47cbamrkFO8U5osEfif/bFnu7lv8='
  },
  data : data
};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: use chrome devtools to compare chrome's request to yours.

Comment: @jdigital yes, that's the first place I checked. Added the cookie from there. Added more headers from giraffesyo suggestion. Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really anything wrong with your code, but HTTP 403 is Forbidden, which means you probably aren't authenticating to the API correctly.

If you want to see exactly what your browser is sending, use the developer tools, go to the network tab, and right click the request then click Copy As > Fetch or Curl. If you use fetch, you can paste that command into your js file and run it directly, or if you use curl (and you're on linux/mac) you can just paste it directly into your terminal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you response. There is some progress. I added a lot more headers and a few other configurations. And got a different error. Anything else I might try?

cause: [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80] {
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 80
  }